# Days and Lectures logic puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

A school is organizing guest lectures on three different subjects:

- Robotics
- English
- General Aptitude

The event is taking place over three days.The eight lectures are named  P,Q,R,S,T,U,V and W,

> - Robotics and English are to be covered in three lectures each while
>     the remaining lectures are for general aptitude
> - Lecture P, R and S to be on different days
> - Lecture V and W should come on the same day
> - Lecture Q cannot be put up with P, W and S
> - Q and U lectures happen on the same day
> - Lecture P is one Robotics and is held one day before R
> - Lecture R cannot be on the last Day
> - There are at least 3 lectures on day 1

**I don't know how to solve it and please anyone guide me the steps, How to proceed these type of sum, which have to take as the first step**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be quite a bit of missing information. Also I am not sure what your question is as none were asked. But here is all the info that **CAN** be deduced with what you wrote.

> First, P R S are on different days.
> [P][R][S]
> Then Q cannot be with P or S.
> [P][R,Q][S]
> Then U must be with Q.
> D1: [P][R,Q,U][S]
> P is before R and R is not last. So the current order of days is correct.
> D1: [P], D2: [R,Q,U], D3: [S]
> There must be 3 lectures on day 1, Lecture V and W are on the same day and only 3 lectures left to place so V and W must be in day 1.
> D1: [P,V,W], D2: [R,Q,U], D3: [S]
> I assume that lectures on the same subject must be on different days(?) SO there must be at least 2 lectures everyday.
> D1: [P,V,W], D2: [R,Q,U], D3: [S,T]
> P is a robotic lecture, and there is no general aptitude lecture on day 3(?)

Comment: how you are putting V ,W is on Day1, why it cannot be on day 3

Comment: @Learninguser I thought it was obvious when I said 3 lectures must be on day 1, but added more info to clarify.

Comment: i have answer for this question, do you want to see@Stack reader

Comment: Your answer is correct, but finally they added lecture T can happen on anyday,But your explanation is very good,well done @Stack reader